# Python typing with explicit hint not used

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

Why in the following code, `a` is not seen as being of type `LineString`? Pyright does not see any issue there with using a as an `int`.

```py
from typing import cast

import shapely
from shapely.geometry.linestring import LineString

def get_line_string() -> LineString:
    return cast(LineString, shapely.from_wkt("LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)"))

a: int = get_line_string()
print(a + 1)
```

Shapely is not properly stubbed, but that's why I thought that using `cast` and explicit type hint should do the trick.

How can I get an error from pyright when I try to type `a` to `int`?

I am using shapely as an example here, but this is a generic question.

If I add myself stubs:

```
# in typings.shapely.__init__.pyi
def from_wkt(geometry:str) -> LineString:  ...
```

Then my editor (vscode/pylance) sees that `from_wkt` does return `LineString`, but the error is still not caught.

Comment: Did you installed stub files for shapely?

Comment: No, shapely is not properly stubbed. That's why I am putting explicit `cast` and type hints.

Comment: I think it's being ignored by the type system and considered `Any`. Just guessed.

Comment: @S.B exactly: `from shapely.geometry.linestring import LineString` is meaningless for type checker if `shapely` is neither typed (`py.typed` marker) nor stubbed. To confirm, `reveal_type(LineString)` will show `Any` as such type. There is no way around, either add `py.typed` manually to the package (via fork or as a build step), or install stubs for it.